# Solving an integral that involves the quantile function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\mu_1}\exp\{-\rho_{\tau_1}(y-\mu_1)-\rho_{\tau_2}(y-\mu_2)\}\mathbb{I}_{\tau_1<\tau_2}\mathbb{I}_{\mu_1<\mu_2}\,dy$$
without much success. Here $\rho_\tau(u) = \tau u + (\tau-1)u\mathbb{I}_{u<0}$  is the quantile function (see Wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression)), $(\mu_1, \mu_2)\in R^2$, with and $(\tau_1, \tau_2)\in (0,1)^2.$

I've tried with this:

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-(tau1*(y - mu1)*If[y - mu1 >= 0, 1, 0] + (tau1-1)*(y - mu1)*
       If[y - mu1 < 0, 1, 0])]*
  Exp[-(tau2*(y - mu2)*If[y - mu2 >= 0, 1, 0] + (tau2-1)*(y - mu2)*
       If[y - mu2 < 0, 1, 0])], {y, -Infinity, mu1}, Assumptions -> {tau1 < tau2}]
```

but the output I get is the input its self. Any idea about how to fix it?

**Edit**: the answer is obviously

$$\frac{e^{(2-\tau_1-\tau_2)\mu_1-\bar\mu}}{2-\tau_1-\tau_2}\,,$$
where $\bar\mu = (1-\tau_1)\mu_1+(1-\tau_2)\mu_2.$

Comment: Try defining the function using `Piecewise` instead, perhaps.

Comment: Plots of your integrand (using random values for your `tau`s and `mu`s since none were provided) look pretty explosive for negative values of `y`. Do you have any reason for supposing that the integral exists? Are there tighter bounds you can put on your parameters?

Comment: @march tried with "Picewise" and "UitStep" but neither worked. aardvark2012 you are  right, there are typos in my Mathematica code and in the definition of the quantile function. Now it must be ok. I can solve it analytically obviously, as such integral is really trivial, but I find it strange that Mathematica is not able to find the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the assumption that `mu1 < mu2`. Also use [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) rather than [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html)

```
int = Assuming[{tau1 < tau2, mu1 < mu2},
  Integrate[
    Exp[-(tau1*(y - mu1)*Boole[y - mu1 >= 0] + (tau1 - 1)*(y - mu1)*
          Boole[y - mu1 < 0])]*
     Exp[-(tau2*(y - mu2)*Boole[y - mu2 >= 0] + (tau2 - 1)*(y - mu2)*
          Boole[y - mu2 < 0])], {y, -Infinity, mu1}] // Simplify]

(* ConditionalExpression[-(E^(-(mu1 - mu2) (-1 + tau2))/(-2 + tau1 + tau2)), 
 tau1 + tau2 < 2] *)
```

Comparing to expected result

```
(int // Normal) == 
  Exp[(2 - tau1 - tau2) mu1 - ((1 - tau1) mu1 + (1 - tau2) mu2)]/
   (2 - tau1 - tau2) // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: The use of `Boole[]` is not required in V13. (It probably was in 2018, but I can't check when the handling of `If[]` was made more robust.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) on the integrand and include all the assumptions:

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-(tau1*(y - mu1)*If[y - mu1 >= 0, 1, 0] + (tau1 - 1)*(y - mu1)*
        If[y - mu1 < 0, 1, 0])]*
   Exp[-(tau2*(y - mu2)*If[y - mu2 >= 0, 1, 0] + (tau2 - 1)*(y - mu2)*
        If[y - mu2 < 0, 1, 0])] //
  PiecewiseExpand,
 {y, -Infinity, mu1},
 Assumptions -> {0 < tau1 < tau2 < 1, mu1 < mu2}]  (* N.B. *)
(*  -(E^(-(mu1 - mu2) (-1 + tau2))/(-2 + tau1 + tau2))  *)

(* OP's form of the answer *)
mubar = (1 - tau1) mu1 + (1 - tau2) mu2;
Exp[(2 - tau1 - tau2) mu1 - mubar]/(2 - tau1 - tau2) // Simplify
(*  -(E^(-(mu1 - mu2) (-1 + tau2))/(-2 + tau1 + tau2))  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I defined the quantile function using `HeavisideTheta` as

```
rho[u_, tau_] := tau u + (1 - tau) u HeavisideTheta[-u];
```

When I tried to integrate your expression using this definition, I was informed that the integral diverges. I tried the expression below instead

```
Integrate[
Exp[rho[(y - mu1), tau1] + rho[(y - mu2), tau2]] HeavisideTheta[
tau2 - tau1], {y, -Infinity, mu1}]
```

and got as result

> HeavisideTheta[tau2 - tau1]E^(mu1 - mu2)/2

when `mu1 <= mu2` and

> HeavisideTheta[tau2 - tau1]E^((mu1 - mu2) tau2)/(1 + tau2)

otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. There was a typo in my definition of the quantile function...sorry for that. So, obviously, your answer is incorrect.